# Python install Global Arrays Toolkit on Ubuntu

Tags: python, c, mpi

I am trying to install Global Arrays (http://hpc.pnl.gov/globalarrays/index.shtml) to my laptop. As described in installation guide, I do ./confgure and then make. Here I get error:

```
ma/ma.c: In function 'list_verify':
ma/ma.c:1379:17: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
                 (void)printf(preamble);
                 ^
ma/ma.c:1403:17: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
                 (void)printf(preamble);
                 ^
ma/ma.c:1428:17: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
                 (void)printf(preamble);
                 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [ma/ma.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dimka/UT/Master/Parallel computing/Project/ga-5-3'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dimka/UT/Master/Parallel computing/Project/ga-5-3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What might be the problem? I need only Python module. Also, can I use Python module without installing whole GAT?

Comment: hey you again ran into installation problem :)

Comment: Yes, but it is a bit different error. I am trying to install framework, but get an error.

Comment: There is probably `-Wall` somewhere in your compiler flags (e.g. as part of `CFLAGS` in the makefile).

Comment: I checked, no I do not have that flag in makefile.

Answer (score 0):

> `cc1: some warnings being treated as errors`

The causal option is `-Werror`; remove it or disable it selectively with `-Wno-error=format-security`. See also e. g. [How to compile without warnings being treated as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561283/2413201)