# Android kernel compile error gcc6 linaro 6

Tags: android, gcc, compiler-errors, kernel, linaro

I'm trying to compile using Linaro 6 and I'm receiving this error which I believe have something do do with GCC 6? I'm very amateur with compiling kernels or coding for that matter, but I couldn't figure this out even search similar terms:

```
  CC      drivers/iommu/msm_iommu-v1.o
In file included from include/linux/io.h:22:0,
                 from drivers/iommu/msm_iommu-v1.c:20:
drivers/iommu/msm_iommu-v1.c: In function '__program_context':
drivers/iommu/msm_iommu_hw-v1.h:78:31: warning: result of '16777215 << 14' requires 39 bits to represent, but 'int' only has 32 bits [-Wshift-overflow=]
error, forbidden warning: msm_iommu_hw-v1.h:78
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target 'drivers/iommu/msm_iommu-v1.o' failed
```

this is my GitHUB:

https://github.com/mykesorrel/surnia_kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug with that iommu driver. It's trying to do a bit-shift into an `int` instead of a `long`, an int doesn't have enough bits to complete the operation. I'm guessing the `-Wno-error` isn't used, so all warnings are treated as errors.

This question will help you: [How to compile without warnings being treated as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561261/how-to-compile-without-warnings-being-treated-as-errors)

What I personally do is update `CFLAGS` in my .bashrc (Assuming you're using Linux). This is what I use:

```
# Ensure C builds don't fail on warnings
export CFLAGS="-Wno-error"
export CXXFLAGS="-Wno-error"
```

Comment: Thanks i went with -w instead that seemed to work better, don't know why the other wasn't working.