# How do you keep track of warnings generated while compiling many different source files

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I am using GNU g++ to compile an older c++ project with many source files.  I am trying to get the project to compile without warnings using -Wall for version c++ versions 11 up to 17.

If I delete the entire build directory and remake everything from scratch, a large list of warnings appears.  After fixing warnings generated by a specific file and recompiling, only warnings from that specific file are displayed, since the makefile detects that all other objects are up to date and the .cpp/.h files aren't modified.

Since doing the build from scratch is time consuming.  My solution is digging into directories and deleting the objects, so I can recompile and see the warnings.  This is okay, but somewhat tedious.

Is there any other solution.  Is there a way to force the compiler to exit on a warning as if it was an error?  I'm using GNU g++.

Comment: [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: And if your "older C++ project" uses makefiles (the only build system worth using, btw) have you tried simply executing `make clean`?

Comment: First `make clean` to remove all objects produced in the previous `make`. Then compile and redirect the outputs to a log file `make &> make.log`. You can check `make.log` to find all the warnings.

Comment: Don't use the `make` system.  Build each file individually until there are zero errors and zero warnings.  After all files compile separately with zero warnings and zero errors, run the `make` as rebuild.

Comment: Did not find a dupe, but did find someone with the opposite problem: [How can I compile without warnings being treated as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561261/how-can-i-compile-without-warnings-being-treated-as-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I am using -Werror and editing the makefile to add options for compiling only a few source files at a time.  I think this is the best way.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: You can just use `-Werror -Wfatal-errors` to always stop after the first error - no need to change your build system. See also: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html