# Compiler error while compiling tensorflow_io in curve25519.c

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, object-detection, tensorflow-io

I am trying to compile tensorflow_io onto my Ubuntu 22.04.2 target machine that does not offer GPU nor AVX instruction. I am finding that the compile errors out on curve25519.c. Is there a dependency that I need pre-installed before compiling? Here is the trace:

```
ERROR: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/d7752e78d6f81d5a4b8e51449d25c837/external/boringssl/BUILD:130:11: Compiling src/third_party/fiat/curve25519.c failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/d7752e78d6f81d5a4b8e51449d25c837/sandbox/linux-sandbox/242/execroot/org_tensorflow_io && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/user/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-5.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:/home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf/bin:/home/user/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    TF_HEADER_DIR=/home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/include \
    TF_SHARED_LIBRARY_DIR=/home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow \
    TF_SHARED_LIBRARY_NAME=libtensorflow_framework.so.2 \
    avariable=2 \
  /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boringssl/_objs/crypto/curve25519.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boringssl/_objs/crypto/curve25519.pic.o' -fPIC -iquote external/boringssl -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boringssl -isystem external/boringssl/src/include -isystem bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boringssl/src/include '-fvisibility=hidden' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64' '-march=native' -Wno-sign-compare -Wa,--noexecstack '-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700' -Wall -Werror '-Wformat=2' -Wsign-compare -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow -fno-common '-std=c11' -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c external/boringssl/src/third_party/fiat/curve25519.c -o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/boringssl/_objs/crypto/curve25519.pic.o)
# Configuration: 683c4395567a3d925cdf6244b42f976fe0687d86f7973f0af39694471ed5243f
# Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
external/boringssl/src/third_party/fiat/curve25519.c:511:57: error: argument 2 of type 'const uint8_t[32]' {aka 'const unsigned char[32]'} with mismatched bound [-Werror=array-parameter=]
  511 | int x25519_ge_frombytes_vartime(ge_p3 *h, const uint8_t s[32]) {
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from external/boringssl/src/third_party/fiat/curve25519.c:41:
external/boringssl/src/third_party/fiat/internal.h:117:58: note: previously declared as 'const uint8_t *' {aka 'const unsigned char *'}
  117 | int x25519_ge_frombytes_vartime(ge_p3 *h, const uint8_t *s);
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
external/boringssl/src/third_party/fiat/curve25519.c:831:57: error: argument 2 of type 'const uint8_t *' {aka 'const unsigned char *'} declared as a pointer [-Werror=array-parameter=]
  831 | void x25519_ge_scalarmult_base(ge_p3 *h, const uint8_t *a) {
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from external/boringssl/src/third_party/fiat/curve25519.c:41:
external/boringssl/src/third_party/fiat/internal.h:125:56: note: previously declared as an array 'const uint8_t[32]' {aka 'const unsigned char[32]'}
  125 | void x25519_ge_scalarmult_base(ge_p3 *h, const uint8_t a[32]);
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 619.024s, Critical Path: 20.71s
INFO: 305 processes: 65 internal, 240 linux-sandbox.
```

Background:
I am working on building out CPU only instance of tensorflow.  I have made several successful tensorflow wheel files and they successfully install and run. Intructions followed from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

The trouble comes when I install the Object Detection Framework. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection First problem (solved) was object detection wants tensorflow 2.12.0 which it installed (over my compiled 2.14.0 latest) and failed on illegal instruction, probably AVX. So I compiled tensorflow 2.12.0 with which object detection is happy and leaves my self compiled installation in place.

Which leads to my current problem: Object Detection installs tensorflow_io which is not part of the base source compiled for tensorflow. After installation of tensorflow_io I'm plagued again with "illegal instruction".

So trying to compile tensorflow_io from here https://github.com/tensorflow/io/blob/master/docs/development.md Unfortunately I'm not quite able to follow to the "T". I am on Ubuntu 22.04.2 instead of 20. Also I am not sudo'ing as I am installing tensorflow (and hopefully _io into a conda virtual environment). Other than that I have done everything else.

My goal is to learn the ins and outs on small problem domains before deciding to invest in more appropriate hardware. I also like the idea of not bringing every little thing I want to do up to collab_net. I prefer to see that as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else stumbling on this issue. I finally keyed in on this from the compiler trace `cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`

and found [How can I compile without warnings being treated as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561261/how-can-i-compile-without-warnings-being-treated-as-errors)

I went with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561283/2624395 and changed all 978 instances of -Werror to a more innocuous -Wno-sign-compare in my copy of the project. But in hindsight I should've tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561340/2624395 first on my build command specifying -Wno-error:

`bazel build -s --verbose_failures --copt="-march=native" --copt="-Wno-sign-compare" --copt="-Wno-error" //tensorflow_io/... //tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem/... --local_cpu_resources=2 --experimental_repo_remote_exec`

the compile is lumbering along well past the original compile issue.

compile completed in about an hour. That was the last of my build issues, the framework is running now